# Dataview webpart on Subsite pulling list from Parent Site

Tags: 2010, master-page, data-view-web-part

In a Master Page I need to insert a Data View that pulls information from the parent site. I believe I can do this with a Content Query Web Part but I cannot put a web part like this into a Master Page.

EDIT:
What I want to do is make the contact info for my company editable in the browser. The contact info is in the footer of every master page that will be used on any site and subsite. My current way of doing this is make a list with an entry that has the contact info (phone, address, etc.) and then insert a Data View web part into the footer of the master page. This works fine if I make this contact info on every site but its against my religion to make people change the same thing in 5 places (if they have to change the contact info in the future). What I want to do instead is have 1 list with 1 entry that have the contact info and point to this entry from any site I need to. That way my company can then change the info in a web form in browser without code.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using XsltListViewWebPart for more detailed steps check out the article on my blog - **Display Parent List in SubSite using SharePoint 2010** at http://tad.co.in/?p=764

Answer (score 0):

I would not recomand putting in a master page (or at least create a WebPart Zone and insert it there) as the pages where your master page would be used is unpredictable in most cases.

You mentioned CQWP which means you are using Publishing Site (right?) so you rather create a Page Layout that embeds a  Data-View Web Part which could do the exact same thing (is all about the Data Source) and use that page layout any time you need it.

Additionally if you really want to stick to putting in the master page you could a Delegate control put any control in it (requires a feature for the control).

Comment: Yes I am using a publishing site but my sysadmin setup out sites so there is 1 site collection with a ton of subsites therefore I get blocked when trying to create layouts.

Comment: Is it a matter of permissions then? So you can't get to the list itself?

Comment: No I can get to the list. See my edit above